# Error: 'Access Denied' from jslint on a jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins, jslint

I am running a jenkins job, with jslint plugin. My build fails with the following error, access denied at workspace. Should I give any file permission to the workspace? I am using git to check out the project and the files get checked out all well. Can any one give me some directions with the bellow mentioned error?

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\test\workspace
Checkout:workspace / C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\test\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@10d4b20
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision 13460c60318e0c4859473d848dd81f76073fe34e (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from origin
Seen branch in repository origin/HEAD
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 2 remote branches
Commencing build of Revision 13460c60318e0c4859473d848dd81f76073fe34e (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Checking out Revision 13460c60318e0c4859473d848dd81f76073fe34e (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here
[JSLint] Ready
[JSLint] calling jslint with args[-DxmlOutput=C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\test\workspace/, C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\test\workspace\readme.js]
[JSLint] JSLint path is jar:file:/C:/Program Files/Jenkins/plugins/jslint/WEB-INF/lib/classes.jar!/com/boxuk/jenkins/jslint/JSLintBuilder/jslint.js
FATAL: Wrapped java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\test\workspace (Access is denied) (jslint.js#5732)
org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\test\workspace (Access is denied) (jslint.js#5732)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1773)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.newInstance(MemberBox.java:202)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.constructSpecific(NativeJavaClass.java:281)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.construct(NativeJavaClass.java:200)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.newObject(ScriptRuntime.java:2327)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c6._c149(jslint.js:5732)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c6.call(jslint.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c6._c0(jslint.js:5591)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c6.call(jslint.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:398)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3065)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c6.call(jslint.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c6.exec(jslint.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.evaluateReader(Context.java:1135)
    at com.boxuk.jenkins.jslint.LintRunner.call(LintRunner.java:126)
    at com.boxuk.jenkins.jslint.LintRunner.call(LintRunner.java:28)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
    at com.boxuk.jenkins.jslint.JSLintBuilder.perform(JSLintBuilder.java:116)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:804)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:586)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1603)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:247)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\test\workspace (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.newInstance(MemberBox.java:194)
```

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that you've left the "Log file" parameter of the JSLint plug-in blank. The plug-in is passing an empty filename to JSLint, and the resulting path points to your workspace directory; you can see that here in your log output:

[image]

Under the covers, JSLint is attempting to open a directory for writing, which of course isn't going to work out so you're seeing the "Access is denied" error.

It's not clear from the docs that "Log file" is required, but the problem is fixed by providing a filename for the log file, like so:

[image]

Also, keep in mind that your `target` folder won't exist yet if you're running JSLint as a pre-step, so you'll see another error if you attempt to use that.